# How to avoid duplicate Outlook items when using ActiveSync?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, duplicate

I'm using a Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional device to synchronize my Outlook 2007 data at home with the Exchange Server (via Direct Push) and my Outlook data in the office using ActiveSync 4.5.

Now, whenever I change a contact or task at one of the three possible places (home, phone, office), a random number of contacts or tasks is being duplicated.

What is the root cause for this problem and what can I do to work around it or avoid it altogether?

Comment: I'm aware of articles such as http://www.sperrysoftware.com/Outlook/Outlook-Duplicates.asp but I don't see how they would help _avoid_ the problem.

Comment: My goal is to have the same calendar, contacts and tasks on Home PC, Phone and Office PC.
Here's my current setup
Home->Phone [ActiveSync 4.5] (contacts, calendar, tasks, notes, files)
Office->Phone [ActiveSync 4.5] (notes, files)
Exchange->Phone [Direct Push] (contacts, calendar, email, tasks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would install consistent versions of active sync and then make sure it is set up to synchronize only-bidirectionally with only one of your 3 locations.  This was how I solved that problem between my laptop and desktop at work.

Comment: I noticed I'm using mixed English and German versions of ActiveSync 4.5